# How can I write a loop that adds a specified number of rows to this data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have this data frame below.

```
 my_tibble <- tibble(
  Week_Start_Day = mdy(c("06-06-2022","06-20-2022","07-04-2022")),
  Duration = c(8,1,3),
  Weekly_Hours = c(10,5.5,15.667),
  Project = c("ClientA","ClientB","ClientC")
)
```

You interpret it as follows:

1. Each project has a start day (Week_Start_Day) — the day work begins
2. Each project has a Duration in weeks
3. Each project demands x hours per Week (Weekly_Hours)
4. Each project has a name (Project_Name)

I want to create a separate row for each week of the project so I can visualize it over a weekly view. For example, row 1 has a Duration of 8, meaning the project goes for 8 weeks. Thus, it should be duplicated 7 times. Each duplicated row should have a new Week_Start_Day, which should be 7 more than the prior. So for ClientA we should have a total of 8 rows across 6/6, 6/13, 6/20, 6/27, etc. All other data needs to remain the same.

I have tried numerous loops and all have failed. I attempted manually adding one row just to see if I'd get some inspiration, but I am unable to convert this into a loop. Here is what one instance of adding a new row should look like:

```
my_tibble[4,]$Week_Start_Day <- my_tibble[1,]$Week_Start_Day + 7
my_tibble[4,]$Duration <- my_tibble[1,]$Duration
my_tibble[4,]$Weekly_Hours <- my_tibble[1,]$Weekly_Hours
my_tibble[4,]$Project <- my_tibble[1,]$Project
```

I have thought I could use a while loop and a column Weeks_Remaining which decrements each time. So something like this pseudo-code:

While Weeks Remaining > 1, add a row with Week_Start_Day + 7 and decrement Weeks remaining by 1.

I used the below code to duplicate the rows the correct number of times, but as you can see the Week date field did not increment.

```
my_tibble_1 <- data.frame(lapply(my_tibble, rep, my_tibble$Duration))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loops here:

```r
 my_tibble %>% 
   group_by_all() %>% 
   summarize(Week_beginning = Week_Start_Day + 7 * (seq(Duration) - 1)) 
#>    Week_Start_Day Duration Weekly_Hours Project Week_beginning
#>    <date>            <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>   <date>        
#>  1 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-06-06    
#>  2 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-06-13    
#>  3 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-06-20    
#>  4 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-06-27    
#>  5 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-07-04    
#>  6 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-07-11    
#>  7 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-07-18    
#>  8 2022-06-06            8         10   ClientA 2022-07-25    
#>  9 2022-06-20            1          5.5 ClientB 2022-06-20    
#> 10 2022-07-04            3         15.7 ClientC 2022-07-04    
#> 11 2022-07-04            3         15.7 ClientC 2022-07-11    
#> 12 2022-07-04            3         15.7 ClientC 2022-07-18
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain the use of group_by_all() ?

Comment: In your data set, we could probably just group row-wise to get the groups required for expanding in `summarize`. `group_by_all` is just an easy way to group row-wise in this case without dropping the other variables.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you close to what you are looking for:

```r
tibble(
  Week_Start_Day = mdy(c("06-06-2022","06-20-2022","07-04-2022")),
  Duration = c(8,1,3),
  Weekly_Hours = c(10,5.5,15.667),
  Project = c("ClientA","ClientB","ClientC")
) %>% 
  mutate(
    weeks = map2(Week_Start_Day, Duration, ~ .x + weeks(1:.y-1))
  ) %>% 
  unnest(c(weeks))
```

This will generate a new column `weeks` containing the start date for each of the weeks over the defined duration.